# How to fix Navigator.push throwing error: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '(() => void)

Tags: flutter, future, navigator

Please explain why I am getting this error when trying to open Screen 2 using Navigator.of(context).push:
**type 'Future' is not a subtype of type '(() => void)**

This is the scenario:

1. I have an onPressed: calling my submitEntry() function like this:

`onPressed: () => submitEntry(),`

2. The submitEntry() function performs some validation and then tries to open a new screen and send it an object and an integer:

```
  void submitEntry() async {
    // ... some code to set validationSucceeded = true; ...
    if (validationSucceeded) {
        await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Screen2(
                editObject: currentObject,
                editMode: currentMode)));
    }
  }
```

3. The top of the Screen2 class looks like this:

```
class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen2({
    super.key,
    required this.editObject,
    required this.editMode
  });

  final Activity editObject; 
  final int editMode; 

  @override
  State<Screen2> createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {

    // ... leaving out setting-up code
    
  _setUpScreenData() async {
    // ... leaving out the code that populates the screen's fields
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setUpScreenData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
```

The only difference that I can identify between this push call and others in my app are that this one is occurring in a function called in an onPressed: instead of in the onPressed: itself. But when I tried calling it inside the onPressed: itself, I still got the same error.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: can you try commenting `_setUpScreenData();` if it still fails can you provide full sample snippet that will reproduce the same error.  More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that helped me solve it. The problem had nothing to do with the calling page (it was a mistake I made inside Screen2), but why the heck did the Console highlight the problem in the calling page's Navigator.push line instead of the actual line deep within Screen2's code??

Comment: ig `builder: (BuildContext context) => Screen2(`, also try using [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for future method. like for your case `_setUpScreenData`